# Junit set system property for test not working

Tags: spring, junit

I have an issue that I would have thought I could resolve by now...

I'm writing a few simple tests to hit a couple services...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EndpointTests {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationController applicationController = new     ApplicationController();
    static {
        System.setProperty("audit.enabled", "false");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupProperties() {
        System.setProperty("audit.enabled", "false");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {}

    @Test
    public void testGetApplications() throws Exception  {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/applications/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name",is("XYZ")));
    }
```

Long story short, I need this property disabled when running tests. I've tried setting the property in a static initializer and in @BeforeClass as I've seen on other posts but when it goes into the actual method, it's still its default 'enabled' value and the tests fail.   I'm not using XML configuration so would prefer a code/annotation solution.

Any suggestions on another way I can fix this? Thanks.

UPDATE

Seems like every time my integration test runs:

```
 @Test
    public void testGetApplications() throws Exception  {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/applications/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name",is("paasport-services")));
    }
```

It executes my @Configuration classes on the call to mockMvc.perform...

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration 
...
...
```

So setting the property value in my test class does no good.
Is there any way to get in between and set this one property for my tests? I don't want to really create a separate test application context as it's just one property and everything has been working well for me up to this point.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a much more elegant solution but I simply set a new system property in @BeforeClass on my test class.

My audit is handled by an aspect and I simply check that property I set only in my test class. If it's set to true, the advice doesn't execute.